# CONTAINS(Oracle) vs. MATCH(MySql)

Tags: mysql, oracle

I want to know what I can do to find the same results as in Oracle with MySql DBMS.

For example I use this statement in Oracle:

```
Select *
FROM   PEP INNER JOIN ZUSAMMEN ON PEP.ID = ZUSAMMEN.PEPID
WHERE CONCATINS(ZUSAMMEN.NAMEN, '%Angela% and %Merkel%',0 ) > 0;
```

So I've set a CONTEXT Index on the 'Namen' Column.

Now, in MySql the syntax looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   INNER JOIN ZUSAMMEN ON PEP.ID = ZUSAMMEN.PEPID
WHERE  MATCH(ZUSAMMEN.NAMEN) AGAINST ('Angela Merkel' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

The problem is, that the MySql Statement finds more results than Oracle. 
Oracle finds the exact Name (Angela Dorothea Merkel). 
MySql Not.

How can I build my Syntax for MySql, that MySql finds the same results as Oracle?

Comment: Please clarify: Is it `CONATINS` (as per the title), `CONCATINS` (as per your query) or `CONTAINS` (what I think you mean)?

Comment: Also, your MySQL query is missing the a table (`PEP`?) for the `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to mysql documentation on [fulltext search in boolean mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html):

> In implementing this feature, MySQL uses what is sometimes referred to
>   as implied Boolean logic, in which
>
> - +: stands for AND
> - -: stands for NOT
> - [no operator]: implies OR

You have not indicated any operators, so mysql is searching for records that have either Angela or Merkel present in the `namen` field. Modify the search using the + operator to require both words to be present:

```
MATCH(ZUSAMMEN.NAMEN) AGAINST ('+Angela +Merkel' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Pls note, that the mysql search will still behave slightly differently. The Oracle search should return a record where the name is Angelas Merkels, while the mysql search will not.

Comment: Ok, thanks so far. But if i build this satement in MySql: SELECT * FROM audit.test where match(NAMEN) against('+schröder +hard' in boolean mode ); Than i want that 'hard' is like '%hard%'. So all Names that contains schröder AND hard, somewhere in the name, should found - Like this one: "Schröder GerHARD". In oracle that's works fine.

Comment: Then you cannot use fulltext search in mysql, you have to go back to the basic like pattern `where namen like '%schröder%' and namen like '%hard%'`. Mysql fulltext search only supports trailing patterns ('hard*'), not leading ones.